# Make another user button missing?

Tags: masking

[image]

The Maskedplate has a Fake User button, but there also should be a number button that you can click that would duplicate it and make another identical layer?

I'm trying to duplicate another of the same layer so I don't have to make another mask. Help.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

It was just a matter of making two strips share the same layer. That way, you get the number 2 beside the Maskedplate.